# PayPal Express Checkout Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, paypal

Simple Question. How do I do it.

I have managed to connect to the Paypal web services and using the sand box but I can't even get started.

The documentation is easy enough to understand in the steps you have to follow,   but I just can't get any code to compile never mind run. This is as far as I have got. See below, `PayPalTest` is the name of my service reference

I have marked where it starts going wrong I can't get the parameters right, no matter what I try to declare or instantiate and get an invalid type error (the red wavy line of doom).

What should I be doing. Does anyone have a working sample to share. Yes I can see lots of samples using Ajax, jQuery and what-not. But I can't find anything that does it the way I want to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GenericWebApplication.ApplicationClasses
{
    class PayPalIntegration
    {
        public void PayForGoods()
        {
            PayPalTest.CustomSecurityHeaderType c = new PayPalTest.CustomSecurityHeaderType();

            c.Credentials.Username = "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx";
            c.Credentials.Password = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
            c.Credentials.Signature = "XXxxX-XXXxxXXxX.XXXXXXXxxXXxXX-XXXXxxxXXXXxxXXXXxxXXX";

            PayPalTest.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient cl = new PayPalTest.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient();
            //I get stuck here
            PayPalTest.SetExpressCheckoutReq r = new PayPalTest.SetExpressCheckoutReq();

            PayPalTest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType d = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
            d.ReturnURL = "";
            d.CancelURL = "";

            PayPalTest.SetExpressCheckoutResponse re = cl.SetExpressCheckout(d, d);

        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]

```
    encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
    encoder["USER"] = APIUsername;
    encoder["PWD"] = APIPassword;
    encoder["SIGNATURE"] = APISignature;
    encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
    encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
    encoder["VERSION"] = SystemFunctions.Settings("PayPalVersion", "")[0].Value;
    encoder["NOSHIPPING"] = "2";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = amt;
    encoder["MAXAMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]  = "GBP";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC"] = "test EC payment";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT"] = SystemFunctions.Shipping;
    //Optional Shipping Address entered on the merchant site
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME"]       = shipToName;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET"]     = shipToStreet;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2"]    = shipToStreet2;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY"]       = shipToCity;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE"]      = shipToState;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP"]        = shipToZip;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE"]= shipToCountryCode;
    encoder["EMAIL"] = SystemFunctions.UserAddress.Email;
    encoder["SOLUTIONTYPE"] = "Sole";
    encoder["LANDINGPAGE"] = "Billing";
    encoder["CHANNELTYPE"] = "Merchant";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = SystemFunctions.TrolleyTotal.ToString("0.00");
    encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"] = "Goods";
    encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"] = SystemFunctions.TrolleyTotal.ToString("0.00");
    encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"]="ABC123";
    encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"] = "1";
```

Comment: I've looked at a gazillion articles across the web and none of them do what I want to do. In fact they all pretty much do no more that Payments Standard which I have already gotten working, question is do I need to bother with Express checkout in that case ?

Comment: Looks to me like you're not following the API requirements. There is a section on how to use Express Checkout here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers and it would appear the "missing piece" in your above code relates to your workflow and not necessarily your code. review the order of things at the above link and you should be on your way. good luck

Comment: You are missing the point. My code does not compile let alone worry about workflow. I have read that article word for word and it doesn't help. From that article everything up to "PayPal API" I have working fine I just can't find the right code to compile to use Express Checkout Api

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal [Code Wizard](http://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php) from the PayPal Developer site has sample ASP.Net for Express Checkout. Just choose ASP.net from the dropdown.

Here is just some of the sample. You can get all of the ASP.Net plus the functions from the PayPal Code Wizard. There are five files that you need to download from the PayPal Code Wizard. I did include the code snippets as will from the PayPal Wizard Site.

This is the section of the code that handles the billing:

```
if (PaymentOption == "PayPal")
{
NVPAPICaller test = new NVPAPICaller();

string retMsg = "";
string token = "";

if (Session["payment_amt"] != null)
{
    string amt = Session["payment_amt"].ToString();

    //Optional Shipping Address entered on the merchant site
    string shipToName           = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME>";
    string shipToStreet        = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET>";
    string shipToStreet2       = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2>";
    string shipToCity           = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY>";
    string shipToState          = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE>";
    string shipToZip            = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP>";
    string shipToCountryCode    = "<PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE>";

    bool ret = test.MarkExpressCheckout(amt, shipToName, shipToStreet, shipToStreet2,
                    shipToCity, shipToState, shipToZip, shipToCountryCode,
                    ref token, ref retMsg);
    if (ret)
    {
        Session["token"] = token;
        Response.Redirect(retMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("APIError.aspx?" + retMsg);
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect( "APIError.aspx?ErrorCode=AmtMissing" );
}
}
```

This is the portion that handles the billing:

```
if (PaymentOption == "PayPal")
{
NVPAPICaller test = new NVPAPICaller();

string retMsg = "";
string token = "";
string payerId = "";

token = Session["token"].ToString();

bool ret = test.GetShippingDetails( token, ref payerId, ref shippingAddress, ref retMsg );
if (ret)
{
    Session["payerId"] = payerId;
    Response.Write ( shippingAddress );    
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("APIError.aspx?" + retMsg);
}
}
```

This is the section that handles Payment Confirmation:

```
if (PaymentOption == "PayPal")
{
NVPAPICaller test = new NVPAPICaller();

string retMsg = "";
string token = "";
string finalPaymentAmount = "";
string payerId = "";
NVPCodec decoder;

token = Session["token"].ToString();
payerId = Session["payerId"].ToString();
finalPaymentAmount = Session["payment_amt"].ToString();

bool ret = test.ConfirmPayment( finalPaymentAmount, token, PayerId, ref decoder, ref retMsg );
if (ret)
{
    // Unique transaction ID of the payment. Note:  If the PaymentAction of the request was Authorization or Order, this value is your AuthorizationID for use with the Authorization & Capture APIs. 
    string transactionId    = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID"]; 

    // The type of transaction Possible values: l  cart l  express-checkout 
    string transactionType = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE"]; 

    // Indicates whether the payment is instant or delayed. Possible values: l  none l  echeck l  instant 
    string paymentType      = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE"]; 

    // Time/date stamp of payment
    string orderTime        = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME"]; 

    // The final amount charged, including any shipping and taxes from your Merchant Profile.
    string amt              = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT"];

    // A three-character currency code for one of the currencies listed in PayPay-Supported Transactional Currencies. Default: USD.    
    string currencyCode = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE"];

    // PayPal fee amount charged for the transaction    
    string feeAmt           = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT"]; 

    // Amount deposited in your PayPal account after a currency conversion.    
    string settleAmt        = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_SETTLEAMT"]; 

    // Tax charged on the transaction.    
    string taxAmt           = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT"];

    //' Exchange rate if a currency conversion occurred. Relevant only if your are billing in their non-primary currency. If 
    string exchangeRate = decoder["PAYMENTINFO_0_EXCHANGERATE"];
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("APIError.aspx?" + retMsg);
}
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks. Thats gotten me a lot further that all the other response I've got but now I am getting the error below, any ideas ? I have checked and set absolutely everything on my PayPal and Developer acounts `
10002
Authentication/Authorization Failed
You do not have permissions to make this API call`

Comment: That specific error message means that your API Signature Credentials are invalid. Either there is a space in the credentials or they are incorrect. The other possibility is to make certain that if you are using Sandbox credentials they are for a Business Sandbox account and you are pointed to sandbox and not live.

Comment: Hmmm. I have been through all the settings. I have a sandbox account and I am using those API credentials. I have made sure that I have enabled ExpressCheckout on my account. The sandbox doesnt have that setting as far as I could see. Any other ideas :)

Comment: Make sure you are using the sandbox API endpoints. [API Endpoints](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ec)

Comment: Yes I am using the sandbox endpoints. I have checked my code thoroughly using break points to check the values being used and I still the the same error.  `10002
Authentication/Authorization Failed
You do not have permissions to make this API call`

Comment: Switch to live mode, put in your live API credentials and endpoints and see if you have the same message.

Comment: Well I am getting closer. Turns out the code you download from Paypal is incomplete it doesn't hook up all the account variables correctly. With that sorted I now have `10400
Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
Order total is missing.` I have been through this document https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/ and set every conceivable variable and still no joy :(

Comment: See my update to my original question showing the parameters that I have set

Comment: Well I am no closer and bouncing emails back and forth to Paypal. Next to them actually writing the code for me and making this work they are of little help but I will persevere with it. I have found hundreds of articles with the same problem but no solutions so I'm guessing more than a few will be please to see a solution, if I ever get to one.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I used the code downloaded from Paypal which I found does not work out of the box. I had to do some tinkering with it to get it to compile never mind make a successful request.

I used CURL (mentioned in their developer docs) to debug what was actually being sent over to Paypal. I stopped my code via break point and manually copy pasted the request string in. SUCCESS. So then I started digging through the PayPal code and found this code.

```
public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest) //CallNvpServer
{
    string url = pendpointurl;

    //To Add the credentials from the profile
    string strPost = NvpRequest +"&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
```

It appends your API details to the end of the request string if your API details are set in the global variables (Who said global variables were bad practice).

This is the problem as I've already included my API details in 'MarkExpressCheckout`.

```
public bool MarkExpressCheckout(string amt, ...
    '''
    encoder["USER"] = APIUsername;
    encoder["PWD"] = APIPassword;
    encoder["SIGNATURE"] = APISignature;
```

So essentially the request string has my API details at the start and end. It looks like the presence of API details marks a new request, which wont have any cart details associated with it hence the 10400 error.

The Paypal code URLEncode's everything before sending so them telling me it was a URLEncoding problem was a red herring.

In my case the fix was to change this line in `HttpCall` from this

```
    string strPost = NvpRequest +"&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
```

to this

```
    string strPost = NvpRequest;
```

And hey presto, up comes Paypal. I really hope this solution helps someone out as its given me a right headache. Or is it those that have had it are keeping schtum about their solution to it.

Now on to the next problem which I have no doubt will see another question posted here.